# Creating a Regex to replace characters

Tags: c#, regex

I want to build Regex in C#, the Regex maches char and swap it to another clone char. (e.g. swape 1 to 2,but 2 to 4 etc.)

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more detail about **exactly** what you're trying to do, what you've tried so far, what about it isn't working, etc.

Comment: I tried to build Regex for another language from English. for example in english I try to replase a to A and b to B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a MatchEvaluator. Example:

```
string s = "asdf12345";

s = Regex.Replace(s, "[123]", m => {
  switch (m.Value) {
    case "1": return "2";
    case "2": return "3";
    case "3": return "1";
  }
  return m.Value;
});

Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
asdf23145
```

You can also do the same by getting the string as a character array, replace the characters you want, and create a string from the array:

```
char[] c = s.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++) {
  switch (c[i]) {
    case '1': c[i] = '2'; break;
    case '2': c[i] = '3'; break;
    case '3': c[i] = '1'; break;
  }
}
s = new String(c);
```